# Function Store not save in database laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8, php-7.4, laragon

I m using laravel 8 controller for saving text input type using "Store function".My input for 'name' are not stored in database when i submited it.

Here is my blade

```
<form class="text-center  p-4" action="{{ route('store') }}" method = "POST">
@csrf

<div class="mb-3">
 <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">names</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name">
</div>

 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

Here is my ProductController.php

```
public function create()

{

return view('products.create');

}

public function store(Request $request)
{
 $request->validate([

'name' => 'required',
'detail' => 'required',

 ]);

 Product::create($request->all());
 $products -> save();

 return redirect('/saving-list') ->with('success','Umrah record has been updated');

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your parameter is not complete, `'detail' => 'required'` but it's not found

you need new value input `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="detail" placeholder="detail" name="detail">`

and you have to add attribute `name` in every input

for complete code like this bellow

```
<form class="text-center  p-4" action="{{ route('store') }}" method = "POST">
@csrf

<div class="mb-3">
 <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">names</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="detail" name="detail" placeholder="detail">
</div>

 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

and for save or store method https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts

```
$product= new Product;
$product->name = $request->name;
$product->detail= $request->detail;
$product->save();
```

or like this

```
$product= Product::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'detail' => $request->detail,
]);
```